# Recursion removing list elements Python

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

need to write a recurive function to remove elements of list but keep the arrays in the result such as.

```
def remove_words(listx):
    for element in listx:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            remove_words(element)
        else:
            listx.remove(element)

    return listx
```

`remove_words(["a", "b", ["c"]])` would return `[[]]`

My code returns `["b",[]]` for some reason it's missing an element.

Comment: You remove an element of a `list` while iterating it. Do **not** do that. You remove the first element and when the index moves on, the new second element is the formerly third... find a way to avoid that!

Comment: You are removing element from list while iterating so just create a copy of list inside function and return that list

Comment: Do you _want_ to modify your list in-place, or can you create a new list?

Comment: Can you provide a code example using this logic please? @tobias_k It doesn't matter, just needs to return proper nested lists.

Comment: Why did you specify a recursive solution? Mixing an iterative approach (for) with recursion is odd. If you want a recursive solution, this is not a very good start.

Comment: @TimRichardson I disagree. OP basically has a tree with arbitrary depth and unknown number of children. The first calls for recursion, the second for iteration. (It certainly _could_ be done purely recursively or iteratively, but I think the basic approach is sound, apart from the modify-while-iterating problem.)

Comment: OK, I jumped to conclusions (reputation of 1 point, name is student127). I disagree that it is sound: it is buggy, hard to read and poorly performant :)

Comment: I deleted my hint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively emptying a nested list while preserving its structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245128/recursively-emptying-a-nested-list-while-preserving-its-structure)

Answer (score 2):

Do not remove elements from a collection while iterating it. Repeated calls to `list.remove` are also not ideal performance-wise since each removal (from a random index) is `O(N)`. A simple way around both issues would be the following comprehension:

```
def remove_words(listx):
    return [remove_words(e) for e in listx if isinstance(e, list)]
```

The seemingly missing base case is a list with no nested lists where an empty list is returned.

If you want to modify the list in-place, you can use slice assignment:

```
def remove_words(listx):
    listx[:] = [remove_words(e) for e in listx if isinstance(e, list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_words(listx):
  if listx == []:
    return []
  elif not isinstance(listx[0], list):
    return remove_words(listx[1:])
  else:
    return [remove_words(listx[0])] + remove_words(listx[1:])

print(remove_words(["a", "b", ["c"]]))
print(remove_words(["a", ["b",["c","d"],"c"], [["f"],["g"]],"h"]))
```